# Transferring file from local machine to server in WinSCP using Java

Tags: java, scp, jsch, winscp, jcifs

I want to write a notepad file and upload it to a WinSCP path.

I used to create those files manually: Open the WinSCP, give the credentials, open the desired path and upload the file.

Now I am in a situation to automate those things. Text will be entered in a text box or fetched from DB, it has to be written in a notepad file and should be uploaded to a WinSCP path. I have implemented writing the file and it is working fine.

Now, how do I upload the file using Java?

Comment: if you want to do it programatically why dont you use SCP directly?

Comment: I havent heard abt SCP sorry , can u help me out with that ??? i Will even try looking into that.

Comment: @aryann assume i have written the file programatically how do I open a connection by giving the Creds and place the file ??

Comment: ragesh, as mentioned by martin using jsch library. There are examples available for what you want to do with jsch.

Answer (score 3):

What you call "WinSCP path" is actually a storage accessible via some file transfer protocol. Most typically a FTP or SFTP site.

For the FTP, you can use for example the `URLConnection` class:
[Uploading to FTP using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17454529/850848)
or the Apache `FTPClient` client class:
[FTPClient - Java, upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5925572/850848)

For the SFTP, you can use JSch Library:
[How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14617/850848)

If you really want to use WinSCP, you can interact with WinSCP scripting interface from Java. See a code sample in the following question:
[How to know whether SFTP was successful or not in WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21060737/850848)